Every mouse click makes the damage script play one additional more time
I am very new to roblox development and was coding a gun script that decreases damage the further away you are, every time you shoot the gun the damage script will play one additional time. if you click anywhere 3 times the damage will be tripled because the script is ran 3 times.
This script is named "server" and is a normal script

script.Parent.Fall.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr,guy)
    script.Parent.Shot.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr,target)
        
            for _, player in pairs((game.Players:GetPlayers())) do
            local character = workspace:WaitForChild(guy)
            local part = target
            local partPosition = part.Position
            if not character then
                continue
            end
            local humanoidRootPart = character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
            if not humanoidRootPart then
                continue
                end
            local humanoidRootPartPosition = humanoidRootPart.Position
            local distanceBetweenPlayerAndPart = (humanoidRootPartPosition - partPosition).Magnitude
            print(distanceBetweenPlayerAndPart)
            local damage = 100 - 1.5 * distanceBetweenPlayerAndPart
            
            if target:IsDescendantOf(plr.Character) then
                print("Cant KYS")
            else
                if target.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                    if damage > 0 then
                        target.Parent.Humanoid.Health -= damage
                        print(target.Parent, "Got shot for", damage, "Health")
                        
                    else
                        print("Too far away to hit, try a gun with longer range")

                    end
                    
                else
                end
            end
            
            
            
        end
        
        
    end)

    
    
end)



this is a assosiated local script named "local"
local mouse = game.Players.LocalPlayer:GetMouse()
local guy = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name

mouse.Button1Down:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.Shot:FireServer(mouse.Target)
    script.Parent.Fall:FireServer(guy)
    
end)



both scripts as well as their remote events are children of a tool which is a child of the starterpack
From my testing the further away part of the script does not seem to affect the weird damage mechanic.
When you hit a damageable rig the damage does not reset but keeps increasing
More maybe helpful info is when you click it displays the distance from where you clicked. If you click once it displays it once, then clicking again makes it twice, clicking again however makes it 4 times, than 7, than 11 than, than 22. and this keeps going.
Again i have no idea what i am doing and any info would be greatly appreciated

dont bind an event inside another event. now, everytime Fall is triggered it binds Shot so if Fall is triggered 3 times there will be 3 event listeners for Shot.

You connect your function handling the shot again every time script.Parent.Fall is fired.
Move script.Parent.Shot.OnServerEvent:Connect() outside of script.Parent.Fall.OnServerEvent:Connect().

As @River said:every time the 'Fall.OnServerEvent' function is triggered,the "Shot.OnServerEvent" will be connect again.So, there are several Shot.OnServerEvent functions being triggered where you can't see them.
I can provide you with two ways to write：
script.Parent.Fall.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr,guy)
   local shotConnectEvent = script.Parent.Shot.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr,target)
       --you code
       shotConnectEvent:disconnect()
   end                       
end

script.Parent.Fall.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr,guy)
    script.Parent.Shot.OnServerEvent:Once(function(plr,target)
        --you code
    end                       
end

Of course, I haven't verified the feasibility of these two writing methods, I hope it can help you.
